# Motivation for study of parabolic manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, potential-theory

Why separate the complete Riemannian manifolds that admit and those that do not admit positive Green function?
 In summary, what is the motivation for studying parabolic and non-parabolic manifolds?

Comment: You may get more and better answers by adding the tag 'potential theory'.

Answer (score 3):

One that comes to mind is that parabolicity of a Riemannian manifold is equivalent to recurrence of its Brownian motion, e.g. of the Markov process whose infinitesimal generator is $\frac12\Delta$.

See theorem 5.1 in

Grigor’yan, A. (1999). Analytic and geometric background of recurrence and non-explosion of the Brownian motion on Riemannian manifolds. Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 36(02), 135–250. https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-99-00776-4